# c# having problems wtih simple exercise

Tags: c#

So, I'm currently a beginner in C#, and I have an exercise to solve as my homework - the user enters a whole number from the console that is between 0 and 100 including, and the english word of the number is written on the console , so "one" if the input is 1, "two" if the input is 2, "twenty five" if the input is 25 and so on. Problem is, for some reason I only get 84/100 points when I use the judge automated system that tests my program, and I can't understand why, I don't see any mistakes in my code, here it is:

```
class Program
{ 
    static void Main()
    {
        var a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (a < 20)
        {
            if (a == 0) Console.WriteLine("zero");
            else if (a == 1) Console.WriteLine("one");
            else if (a == 2) Console.WriteLine("two");
            else if (a == 3) Console.WriteLine("three");
            else if (a == 4) Console.WriteLine("four");
            else if (a == 5) Console.WriteLine("five");
            else if (a == 6) Console.WriteLine("six");
            else if (a == 7) Console.WriteLine("seven");
            else if (a == 8) Console.WriteLine("eight");
            else if (a == 9) Console.WriteLine("nine");
            else if (a == 10) Console.WriteLine("ten");
            else if (a == 11) Console.WriteLine("eleven");
            else if (a == 12) Console.WriteLine("twelve");
            else if (a == 13) Console.WriteLine("thirteen");
            else if (a == 14) Console.WriteLine("fourteen");
            else if (a == 15) Console.WriteLine("fifteen");
            else if (a == 16) Console.WriteLine("sixteen");
            else if (a == 17) Console.WriteLine("seventeen");
            else if (a == 18) Console.WriteLine("eighteen");
            else Console.WriteLine("nineteen");
        }
        else if (a == 20 || a == 30 || a == 40 || a == 50 || a == 60 || a == 70 || a == 80 || a == 90 || a == 100)
        {
            if (a == 20) Console.WriteLine("twenty");
            else if (a == 30) Console.WriteLine("thirty");
            else if (a == 40) Console.WriteLine("forty");
            else if (a == 50) Console.WriteLine("fifty");
            else if (a == 60) Console.WriteLine("sixty");
            else if (a == 70) Console.WriteLine("seventy");
            else if (a == 80) Console.WriteLine("eighty");
            else if (a == 90) Console.WriteLine("ninety");
            else Console.WriteLine("hundred");
        }
        else
        {
            if (a / 10 == 2) Console.Write("twenty ");
            else if (a / 10 == 3) Console.Write("thirty ");
            else if (a / 10 == 4) Console.Write("forty ");
            else if (a / 10 == 5) Console.Write("fifty ");
            else if (a / 10 == 6) Console.Write("sixty ");
            else if (a / 10 == 7) Console.Write("seventy ");
            else if (a / 10 == 8) Console.Write("eighty ");
            else Console.Write("ninety ");
            if (a % 10 == 1) Console.WriteLine("one");
            else if (a % 10 == 2) Console.WriteLine("two");
            else if (a % 10 == 3) Console.WriteLine("three");
            else if (a % 10 == 4) Console.WriteLine("four");
            else if (a % 10 == 5) Console.WriteLine("five");
            else if (a % 10 == 6) Console.WriteLine("six");
            else if (a % 10 == 7) Console.WriteLine("seven");
            else if (a % 10 == 8) Console.WriteLine("eight");
            else Console.WriteLine("nine");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: holy mother of god that's a lot of if statements

Comment: We can't know what are the automatic judge requirements. Clean code, smarter way of doing it or whatever. You should ask your professor.

Comment: Try to run a for loop from 0 to 100 instead of user input, that run the same method, check if you get all the correct texts, if not, then the code is fine but you lost points about how it is written - 100% you don't need so many if-elses

Comment: maybe you should print "one hundred" instead of "hundred"?

Comment: Is it possible you lose points because you give a result which is incorrect if the user enters a number above 100, when you would be better to return an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comment we can't know the judge automated system requirments for your homework. You need to ask your professor.

Here little smarter implementation of your problem just to know how to approach problems like this in future.

```
var zeroToNighteenArr= new[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", .. till 19 };
var numbersDividedByTenArr = new[] {"zero", "ten" "twenty", "thirty", "forty", ... untill 100 };

if(userInput<20)
{
    Console.WriteLine(zeroToNigteenArr[userInput]);
}
else
{
    //in numbers to numbersDividedByTenArr you can remove the "zero" and "ten", if you want to copy same definition of words
    //but in this case you need to write it numbersDividedByTenArr[userInput/10 -2]  to receive proper result.
    string result = numbersDividedByTenArr[userInput/10];

    result += userInput%10 != 0 ? $" {zeroToNigteenArr[userInput%10]}": "";
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Here we are using the benefit of arrays and we can take element of the array by his index. In our implementation of array you put on index 0-> "zero", 1->"one" and so on. In this way when we wrote `zeroToNighteenArr[userInput]` you receive the word representation of this number.

Comment: Even though you acknowledge that the requirements for the judge automated system are unknown, it's still arguably too soon to answer.  Putting that aside, you essentially "fix" the OP's problem by completely rewriting his code. It's not a good way to learn because no one knows what the original cause of the problem is.   Learning is key for the OP I would think.  Also, considering the style of the OP's code, arrays maaaay be too soon for the OP.   Circumstances aside, I do like your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a bold guess, so please go easy on me.

When the `Console.Out` property is initialized  the `AutoFlush` property of the underlying `TextWriter` is set to `true`. To this effect, the result of your first call to `Console.Write` for the first word, `"twenty "`, `"thirty "`, etc. may cause the underlying buffer to be flushed.

I speculate that your professors' code might be using a `StreamReader` to read only these few characters that arrive in the first buffer, instead of continuing up until `CRLF` or when your application exists, therfore resulting in a mismatch to the expected value.

In other words, it looks like you broke your professors' app and here's how you can confirm:

If the following program scores **0**/100 then I'll bet your professors' app mistakenly fails to read your entire console output stream before your application exists.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("o");
    Console.Out.Flush(); // force it
    Console.WriteLine("ne");
}
```

Comment: Funnily enough this actually does work, gives me a point

Comment: Well, it was worth a try. Still baffled, though.

Comment: I'm curious to see your professors' code. You could always try [decompiling](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download/) it...